# Python How to remove characters from a string inside a list

Tags: python, string, list, character, strip

I've been playing around with my code for quite some time now. I wanna replace a string of text from the values returned by the `each_div` variable which returns a whole bunch of parsed values from a webpage.

```
def scrape_page():
    create_dir(project_dir)
    page = 1
    max_page = 10
    while page < max_page:
        page = page + 1
        for each_div in soup.find_all('div',{'class':'username'}):
            f.write(str(each_div) + "\n")
```

If I run this code it will parse data from the username class from a html page. The problem is that it returns it like this:

```
<div class="username">someone_s_username</div>
```

What I've been trying todo is strip the `<div class="username">` and `</div>` part away so it would only return the actual username instead of the html. If anyone have an idea on how to accomplish this that'll be terrific, thank you

Comment: Can't you refer directly to the textual content of said div by sth like: `each_div.string`

Comment: Lol, thanks man didn't even know..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use Python's **replace** method:

```
for each_div in soup.find_all('div',{'class':'username'}):
    each_div = each_div.replace('''<div class="username">''',"")
    each_div = each_div.replace("</div>","")
    f.write(str(each_div) + "\n")
```

Alternatively, you can **split** the string to obtain the part you want:

```
for each_div in soup.find_all('div',{'class':'username'}):
    each_div = each_div.split(">")[1]  # everything after the first ">"
    each_div = each_div.split("<")[0]  # everything before the other "<"
    f.write(str(each_div) + "\n")
```

Oh, I just remembered, I believe you could be able to do simply this:

```
for each_div in soup.find_all('div',{'class':'username'}):
    f.write(str(each_div.text) + "\n")
```

Comment: Thank you! @schwobaseggl commented a little bit earlier but since it was a comment I will mark you answer as solved anyway